# Format verbose copy content on unix command line (bash script)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to copy from one directory to another while displaying the copied content. While I do know that --verbose shows the copied files, I would like to format it in my own way. For example

```
cp -u $SOUCE $DEST
These files were copied from origin directory to new directory:
a   b    c
```

The closest thing I have found is to use --verbose but its not what I'm looking for

Comment: `rsync -ui "$SRC" "$DST" | myformatter`

Comment: If you are using rsync as cp, you probably want to add a  slash on the source or SRC will be copied into DEST/SRC .